# Bokeh: Unable to plot legend

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I am not sure how to add legend to my plots based on updates to the Bokeh Library. Here is my code -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deepakgthomas/Lemonade_Sales/main/Lemonade_Lab8.csv'
lemon = pd.read_csv(url)
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
source_Q4 = ColumnDataSource(lemon)
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
output_notebook()
p = figure(title = "Lemon and Orange Sales by Temperature")
p.circle("Temperature", "Lemon", source = source_Q4, color = "green", size = 8, legend = dict(value = "Lemon"))
p.triangle("Temperature", "Lemon", source = source_Q4, color = "orange", size = 8, legend = dict(value = "Orange"))
p.legend.location = "top_left"
show(p)
```

However, this gives me the warning -

```
"BokehDeprecationWarning: 'legend' keyword is deprecated, use explicit 'legend_label', 'legend_field', or 'legend_group' keywords instead
BokehDeprecationWarning: 'legend' keyword is deprecated, use explicit 'legend_label', 'legend_field', or 'legend_group' keywords instead"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the Warning states, use `legend_label` instead of `legend`. For more information, [check the user guide](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#legends).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deepakgthomas/Lemonade_Sales/main/Lemonade_Lab8.csv'
lemon = pd.read_csv(url)
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
source_Q4 = ColumnDataSource(lemon)
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
output_notebook()
p = figure(title = "Lemon and Orange Sales by Temperature")
p.circle("Temperature", "Lemon", source = source_Q4, color = "green", size = 8, legend_label = "Lemon")
p.triangle("Temperature", "Orange", source = source_Q4, color = "orange", size = 8, legend_label = "Orange")
p.legend.location = "top_left"

show(p)
```